# Freely available texts in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

Can anyone tell me a good reference to start in algebraic geometry?
There is already a post on this theme, but all books from there are extremely expensive here in my country, Brazil.

Is one of those a good book?

[Introduction Algebraic Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1503381536)

[Introduction to algebraic geometry by Serge lang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1614276277)

Comment: Vakil's text is free online: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/

Answer (score 0):

***Algebraic Geometry (Part I):  Schemes, with examples and exercises*** (Advanced Lectures in Mathematics) by Ulrich Görtz and Torsten Wedhorn (Vieweg+Teubner Verlag) is fine and not too expensive.  (I like the examples.)

Answer (score 0):

Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* is the standard reference which is excellent. Griffiths and Harris' *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* is also very good, having a more complex geometric approach. Shafarevich's books on algebraic geometry are very nice, too.